# Join list into string by preserving quotes if present

Tags: python-3.x, list

Example

```
items = ["1,2", "3", "4"]
```

Expected output:

```
'"1,2", 3, 4' # string. joined bypreserving quotes
```

I have tried

```
",".join(items)
```

But it gives:

```
"1, 2, 3, 4"
```

Is there a hint for a way to do this?

Comment: None of the strings in the list `items` contain quote characters, though, so there's nothing to preserve

Comment: Are you trying to generate CSV files? If so, use a CSV library

Comment: I am trying to write to stdout.

Comment: @KishanMehta `','.join(items)` already works and gives your expected output – at least with your updated question

Comment: I checked it again I updated the question wrongly. O.G question was correct and with that I am not able to preserve quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to convert int but keep strings as it is, then this would help :

```py
def foo(bar : list) -> list:
    x = list()
    for i in bar:
        try:
            x.append(int(i))
        except:
            x.append(i)
    return x
```

Result (matching your expected result) :

```py
>>>items = ["1,2", "3", "4"]
>>>foo(items))
['1,2', 3, 4]
```

It seems like you are trying to work with csv files, if that's the case then using the in-built csv module will help.

Comment: I need string not list

Answer (score 0):

Use json.dumps to get it along with quotes:

```
import json
items = ["1,2", "3", "4"]
json.dumps(items)
```

Comment: This is list inside string. I need string like this `'"1,2", 3, 4'`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to serialize lines to be used in a CSV file? If so, a csv library such as [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) might offer everything you need, including handling of edge cases that you cannot think of at the moment.

If CSV is not, what you are after, you can detect the comma in the input and then wrap it in quotes. For instance with a list comprehension:

```
a = ['1,2', '3', '4']
print(','.join(['"' + x + '"' if ',' in x else x for x in a]))
print(','.join(['"%s"' % x if ',' in x else x for x in a])) # with % operator
print(','.join([f'"{x}"' if ',' in x else x for x in a])) # with f-strings
```

Or delegate to `json.dumps` as suggested in [Niusoski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17184842/niusoski)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70322021/112968), but strip leading and trailing braces:

```
import json
a = ['1,2', '3', '4']
print(json.dumps(a)[1:-1])
print(json.dumps(a).strip('[]')) # doesn't correctly handle nested arrays
```